# Reading RPM tags in PHP

Tags: php, rpm

I'm trying to read the information on an RPM file through PHP.  I know there is a PECL extension, but that would involve recompiling PHP on a server where I don't have that ability.  So I'm looking for some way to read the tags off the RPM files.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a PHP script to execute bash command,
a simple example can be like:

```
$info = exec("rpm -qi {$RPM_PACKAGE_FILE}");
```

further study - http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-query.html

Comment: I guess I should also have said that the system I have to write this for does not have RPM installed.

Comment: If you don't have the RPM installed, you cannot do query. Alternatively, you have to get the RPM package either download from web, or get yourself a redhat installation CD.